# PowerShell returning 0 for length of string

Tags: powershell, string-length

I'm trying to get the length of the longest value in a PowerShell object. However, doing this results in `$longenstPackageVersion` keeping it's initial value of `0` -

```
$longenstPackageVersion = 0
$packages | Select-Object @{Name="PackageVersion"; Expression ={"$($_.properties.Id) $($_.properties.Version)"}} | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Length -gt $longenstPackageVersion) { $longenstPackageVersion = $_.Length } }
$longenstPackageVersion
```

So I tried outputting the length of every value, but nothing was output -

```
$packages | Select-Object @{Name="PackageVersion"; Expression ={"$($_.properties.Id) $($_.properties.Version)"}} | ForEach-Object { $_.Length }
```

Finally I tried to first convert each value to a string and then output it's length, but `0` was displayed for every value -

```
$packages | Select-Object @{Name="PackageVersion"; Expression ={"$($_.properties.Id) $($_.properties.Version)"}} | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString().Length }
```

Why is PowerShell unable to check the length of each value like this?  And crucially, how can I amend my code to get it working as expected?

Comment: Your `Select-Object` is creating a custom object and not a string.  In your last example, does it help to change the output to `$_.PackageVersion.Length`?

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks.  So in essence, I've created an Object of Objects, each containing a single `PackageVersion` property?  Can I improve how I'm doing this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Seems odd that you're looking for the package with the longest combination of ID and Version.  Are you looking for the package with the most recent version number?

Comment: I'm trying to get the length of the longest value of a constructed property `PackageVersion`.  This is two existing values concatenated - `$packages.properties.Id` and `$packages.properties.Version`.  I don't necessarily need to construct the property on the fly, I just need that longest length.

Comment: I got that from your code, but why?  Seems a strange thing to do.

Comment: I need to work out the width of a column for some output.  I'm outputting a row at a time so using `"{0,-$longenstPackageVersion" -f "Package Version"` for the header and then `"{0,-$longenstPackageVersion" -f "$($_.properties.Id) $($_.properties.Version)"` for each row.  Because I'm outputting the row and then doing some work, I can't use `Format-Table` to output everything, thus needing to pre-define the column width.  Always open to a better way if there is one though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could output to an array, and then use `Measure-Object` to get the maximum length that I required.

`$longenstPackageVersionLength = (($packages | ForEach-Object { "$($_.properties.Id) $($_.properties.Version)" }) | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum`